# Global Artifactory configuration in Gradle (with credentials)

Tags: gradle

I am very new to Gradle and I need to migrate a company-wide configuration from Ant-Ivy to Gradle.

Our company uses [JFrog Artifactory OSS](https://jfrog.com/open-source/) to manage both a virtual pointer to Maven Central (in order to act as a cache) and company-local repositories.

So I basically have URLs that Gradle must globally use, authenticated with the user's domain password, to retrieve dependencies and publish artifacts made by developers (see note 1).

Artifactory allowed me to generate a configuration and a gradle.properties files containing the credentials, starting from my username.

I generated the following `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://acme.local/artifactory/acme-gradle'
            credentials {
                username = "${artifactory_user}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"
            }
        }
        ivy {
            url 'https://acme.local/artifactory/acme-gradle'
            credentials {
                username = "${artifactory_user}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        //Check for the latest version here: http://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.jfrog.artifactory
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4+"
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"   //The base Artifactory URL if not overridden by the publisher/resolver
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'acme'
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true
            ivy {
                ivyLayout = '[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[module]-[revision](-[classifier]).pom'
                artifactLayout = '[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[module]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]'
                mavenCompatible = true
            }
        }
    }
    resolve {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'acme-gradle'
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true
            ivy {
                ivyLayout = '[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[module]-[revision](-[classifier]).pom'
                artifactLayout = '[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[module]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]'
                mavenCompatible = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the following gradle.properties

```
artifactory_user=${security.getCurrentUsername()}
artifactory_password=${security.getEncryptedPassword()!"........"}
artifactory_contextUrl=https://acme.local/artifactory
```

I would like to understand 1) if it is possible to make those URLs global to all developer machines and not to repeat the `build.gradle` fragment on every project and 2) how to make sure IntelliJ reads the credentials.

#### What I have tried

Gradle is installed via [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org) Package Manager into `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\gradle\tools\gradle-5.1`

I have tried to set Windows environment variable `GRADLE_USER_HOME` to `C:\Users\myself\.gradle`, which existed before I attempted to create the variable.

#### Attempt 1

I have put `gradle.properties` (the password is a meaningful encrypted password in my real file) and `init.gradle` as shown above into %GRADLE_USER_HOME%. Then I told IntelliJ IDEA to use that directory as "Gradle Service Directory Path"

The initial `build.gradle` *project* file was:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
    id 'org.gretty' version '2.2.0'
}


    springVersion='5.1.4.RELEASE'
    springSecurityVersion='5.1.3.RELEASE'
    springPluginsVersion='1.2.0.RELEASE'
    hibernateVersion='5.4.0.Final'
}

group 'com.acme'
version '0.1-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework:spring-core:$springVersion"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-aspects:$springVersion"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-aop:$springVersion"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-beans:$springVersion"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-context:$springVersion"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-context-support:$springVersion"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-expression:$springVersion"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-jdbc:$springVersion"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-orm:$springVersion"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-tx:$springVersion"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-web:$springVersion"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-webmvc:$springVersion"
    compile "org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:$springPluginsVersion"
    compile "org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin:$springPluginsVersion"
    compile "org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:$springPluginsVersion"


    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:$springSecurityVersion"
    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:$springSecurityVersion"
    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap:$springSecurityVersion"
    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:$springSecurityVersion"
    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:$springSecurityVersion"
    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:$springSecurityVersion"
    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-jwt:1.0.9.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework.social:spring-social-web:1.1.6.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework.social:spring-social-core:1.1.6.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap-core:2.3.2.RELEASE"
}
```

Trying to run `gradle` on my project failed miserably both on IntelliJ and command prompt because

```
A problem occurred evaluating initialization script.
> Could not get unknown property 'artifactory_user' for Credentials [username: null] of type org.gradle.internal.credentials.DefaultPasswordCredentials_Decorated.
```

#### Attempt 2

I tried to copy the contents of the global `init.gradle` into the *project-level* `build.gradle` **and** to copy+gitignore the `gradle.properties` file with credentials hardcoded. Everything worked like a charm. But that is obviously not what I want to achieve.

#### Question

How do I load globally-defined properties in `init.gradle`? It is very important for me not to hardcode anything into `init.gradle` because such file will be distributed to **all** developers' machines, requiring them only to hardcode their passwords into a separate file. Future updates to the `init.gradle` file won't be affected by individual credentials.

Note 1: of course this has to be changed: developers should not have **write** access to Artifactory, but only CI server. Anyway, this is the situation for now

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's no more useful

Comment: can you share your solution with us?

Comment: I don't have any